# Преобразование последовательности. Задача

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие задачи: (или на сайте, если удобнее [условие и проверяющая система](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=178))
Задана последовательность, содержащая n целых чисел. Необходимо найти число, которое встречается в этой последовательности наибольшее количество раз, а если таких чисел несколько, то найти минимальное из них, и после этого переместить все такие числа в конец заданной последовательности. Порядок расположения остальных чисел должен остаться без изменения.

Например, последовательность 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2 после преобразования должна превратиться в последовательность 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2.

Требуется написать программу, которая решает данную задачу

Входные данные

Первая строка входного файла INPUT.TXT содержит число n — количество чисел во входной последовательности (3 ≤ n ≤ 200000). Следующая строка содержит входную последовательность, состоящую из n целых чисел, не превышающих по модулю 106. Все числа в строке разделены пробелом.

Выходные данные

В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выводится последовательность чисел, которая получается в результате названного преобразования. Все числа в последовательности должны быть разделены пробелом.

Пример

№   INPUT.TXT   OUTPUT.TXT
1   7
1 2 3 2 3 1 2   1 3 3 1 2 2 2

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  int cur = 1, max = 0, minn = 0, n = 0;

  cin >> n;

  vector<int> a(n), s(n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
    s[i] = a[i];
  }

  sort(s.begin(), s.end());
  s.push_back(-1100000);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(s[i] != s[i + 1]) {
      if(cur > max) {
        max = cur;
        minn = s[i];
        cur = 1;
      }
    } else cur++;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if(a[i] != minn)
      cout << a[i] << ' ';

  for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) cout << minn << ' ';

  return 0;
}
```

Не могу обнаружить ошибку в нем. Не проходит 9 тест(тесты закрыты, их посмотреть также возможности нет.
Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста

Суть моего решения:

1. Ввожу данные в два массива, a и s
2. Сортирую массив s
3. Нахожу самую длинную последовательность подряд идущих чисел в отсортированном массиве
4. Прохожу по исходному массиву, выводя все элементы не равные элементу, из которого состоит самая длинная последовательность
5. В конце вывожу число(столько раз, сколько оно встречается в исходном массиве), из которого состоит самая длинная последовательность

Comment: во первых вы не должны сортировать последовательность, во вторых,  эта программа вообше не решает поставленную задачу

Comment: @ARHovsepyan видимо вы невнимательно прочитали и код, и задачу. Во первых, я не сортировал исходную последовательность, во вторых программа решает поставленную задачу.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan примитивно объяснил суть своего решения в вопросе, возможно это облегчит понимание

Comment: объяснить то объяснили, но выполняете не то. Задача в том, что например и число 5 и число 15 и число 55 могут повторяться одинаковое количество раз и чаще других, тогда вам нужно пятерки поставить конец. Но вы не это же делаете...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я сдал задачу(свое решение, единственная поправка - в ответе) и она прошла все тесты, вероятно, все же, я все делал правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу, глупая ошибка, не в том месте стояло обнуление счетчика текущей длинны последовательности.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  int cur = 1, max = 0, minn = 0, n = 0;

  cin >> n;

  vector<int> a(n), s(n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
    s[i] = a[i];
  }

  sort(s.begin(), s.end());
  s.push_back(-1100000);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(s[i] != s[i + 1]) {
      if(cur > max) {
        max = cur;
        minn = s[i];
      }
      cur = 1;
    } else cur++;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if(a[i] != minn)
      cout << a[i] << ' ';

  for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) cout << minn << ' ';

  return 0;
}
```